# In an Angular 7 application, with reactive forms, how can i modify this method so that it will clear only invalid form controls within a form group?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I need to modify this method, so that when a user clicks on a button, all invalid form controls within the form group they are on, have their values reset or set to null.

The current method consists of this:

```
    disableControl(group: FormGroup){
      Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
      const abstractControl = group.get(key);
      abstractControl.setValue(null)
      abstractControl.disable();
     })
    }
```

When the user clicks on a button, any invalid form controls should be set to null or reset.

Comment: just an FYI, disabling a control removes it's value from the formGroup... not sure what your actual use case is, but what you're after might not be needed

Comment: Ah yes, this is a method we're using in a different scenario.  The new method will be used for another scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the form control is [`invalid`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#invalid):

```ts
disableControl(group: FormGroup) {
  Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
    const abstractControl: AbstractControl = group.get(key);
    if (abstractControl.invalid) {
      abstractControl.reset();
      // .... or
      // abstractControl.setValue(null);
    }
 })
}
```

Comment: awesome, glad to help! :)